# Integrating c++ alongside objective-c in iOS project

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, ios

I've been tasked with adding some c++ code into an iOS project.

The c++ code comes in the form of several libs (.a), and header files with the extension .hpp

I have added these files into the XCode iOS project, and added the paths to the library and header search paths in the project settings, but I am getting compiler errors.

For example, one of the .hpp files contains:

```
`#include <string>`
```

and the error I am getting is *"String: No such file or directory"*

In the same hpp file there is a namespace declaration:

```
`namespace FooBar`
```

and there is an error on this line is *"expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before 'FooBar'"*

I came straight into iOS programming so my experience has been primarily with objective-c. Can anyone offer any advice in terms of the project settings, search paths etc in order to get the c++ working alongside the obj-c?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be that the Objective-C file that's including this header isn't in Objective-C++ mode. Usually you fix this by making your implementation a `.mm` file instead of `.m` since the latter is pure Objective-C.

Comment: Amending my obj-c headers and implementation files as you advised seems to have done the trick! Thank you.